# Receive OAuth bearer token with firebase in payload

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, oauth, retool

I'm trying to receive an OAuth token with a payload similar to this:

```
  name John Jones
  iss https://securetoken.google.com/some-app-name
  aud some-app-name
  auth_time 1608697332
  user_id some-user-id
  sub some-sub
  iat 1608412332
  exp 1608342932
  email some@email.com
  email_verified true
  firebase
    identities
      google.com
         111342112511016950980
      email
         some@email.com
    sign_in_provider google.com
```

The part that is important is the `firebase` section.  The issue I'm having is that the bearer token I'm receiving after using oauth is missing the firebase section.  This is the payload I'm getting:

```
  iss https://accounts.google.com
  azp 1234.apps.googleusercontent.com
  aud 1234.apps.googleusercontent.com
  sub 163433232345016954635
  hd some.hd
  email some@email.com
  email_verified true
  at_hash f643f839471pxJ0gCsA
  name John Jones
  given_name John
  family_name Jones
  locale en
  iat 1601116597
  exp 1607510197
```

I'm using the following settings to receive a bearer token with the above payload:

```
Callback URL: https://oauth.retool.com/oauth/user/oauthcallback
Authorization URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
Access Token URL: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Client ID: *****-*****.apps.googleusercontent.com
Client Secret: *********
Scope: profile email
```

My question is what settings or scope do I need to get a bearer token with firebase in the payload?

For extra information, I'm running this in retool to be able to retrieve a bearer token to use in requests to a graphql server that has an authentication guard.  That guard is a firebase guard (it checks to see if it is a valid firebase user).  The first payload I shared was from a bearer token generated by a client web application, and we want to access similar endpoints in our retool dashboard.

Comment: Running into the same problem, were you able ever to figure this out?

Comment: No wasn't able to figure it out,  I ended up doing something else.  Instead of using oauth, I just logged the user in via the firebase library.  I added the firebase dependencies to retool, and used this to get a firebase oauth token:


```
  const idToken = await firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value)
   .then(({ user }) => user.getIdToken())
   .then(id => {
      return id;
    })

```

Comment: We were able to get it with a custom flow:  Google OAuth, save the idToken, modal (needed because of a timing issue in ReTool), Firebase Rest Request SignIn with OAuth Token from step one.  Save Bearer Token from Firebase Step and use to authenticate original resource. Sounds like you found a work around, but maybe this will help the next person.

Comment: The modal step doesn't do anything, I'm pretty sure it just serves as a placeholder to delay ReTool processing while the firebase callback processes.